# How to see which timestamp columns in the database are UTC timestamps and which ones aren't in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I think I saw a query that shows you which columns are utc and which ones aren't but the query escapes me and I can't seem to find it online... below is what I tried, thanks in advance.

```
select * from all_tab_columns
where data_type like '%TIME%'
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Oracle has two data types which deal with time zones. One is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Here the time zone is explicitly part of the data; different rows in the same table, in the same column with this data type, may have different time zone components. So the question doesn't make sense for this data type; the time zone applies individually to each value, not to the column. The other data type is `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. Here every timestamp with time zone is converted to UTC. The resulting timestamp is stored without time zone information,

Comment: but the data type indicates what that timestamp represents. Do you mean, how can you find all the columns that have this data type? That's easy - query `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` or similar, and filter for the data type.

Comment: nono, what I wanted to find out was whether there was a way for us to tell whether the timestamps in various columns were UTC or if they had to be converted.

Comment: Do you mean columns of data type `TIMESTAMP`? Meaning, not the types that have something to do with time zone? And you want to know if there is a way to tell whether the timestamp was meant to be UTC as opposed to Sydney, for example? There is no such marker in Oracle DB; if you need it, it must be in comments to the table, the documentation for the CREATE TABLE statements (or the specifications for the whole project), or - terrible practice - encoded in the column name, etc. That's why the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle provides two data types which deal with time zones:

`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

However, these are just data type dealing with time zone, it does not mean the stored values are UTC times. In general they can be any time zone but you can convert them to UTC if required.

You query would be

```
select * 
from all_tab_columns
where data_type like 'TIMESTAMP(%) WITH% TIME ZONE';
```

**Appendix regarding your comment:**

On `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` columns you have no time zone, thus you cannot query anything.

On `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` the time is **always** returned at  `SESSIONTIMEZONE` and internally stored at `DBTIMEZONE`, so a query does not make any sense.

On `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` you could run a query as this:

```
select timestamp_tz_column
from your_table
where TO_CHAR(timestamp_tz_column, 'TZR') in ('UTC', 'GMT', '+00:00');
-- or 
where EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM timestamp_tz_column) in ('UTC', 'GMT', '+00:00');
-- or 
where EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM timestamp_tz_column) = 0 
  AND EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_MINUTE FROM timestamp_tz_column) = 0;
```

But actually this query is also useless since you can convert the value like `timestamp_tz_column AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` or `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(timestamp_tz_column)`

Comment: What you said is not true for `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. That data type always has the timestamp in UTC. It is converted to the session local time zone when it is queried (and converted from the local time zone to UTC when inserted into the table).

Comment: @mathguy, No, `timestamp with local time zone` values are stored in `DBTIMEZONE`. However, Oracle recomments to set DBTIMEZONE to UTC, so your statement is not completely wrong.

Comment: LOL - yes, DBTIMEZONE = UTC is so common that I forgot that it's actually DBTIMEZONE. But my main point was that `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` stored values can't be "any time zone." They are all in the same, predetermined time zone, DBTIMEZONE (not UTC, if DBTIMEZONE if set to something other than UTC, as you pointed out).

Comment: @mathguy, of course, physically the timestamp is stored at predetermined time zone (DBTIMEZONE) but from user point of view it is always presented in `SESSIONTIMEZONE` - which could be any time zone. Perhaps now it may turn into philosophy. Mayor point is: data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` deal with time zones, all other data types do not. Regarding "UTC or not UTC" you provided already some valid comments above.

Comment: You bring up an important distinction that the OP must keep in mind: between the "stored" time zone (there is none, DBTIMEZONE is implied though) and the "displayed" time zone, in the case of TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE. Or perhaps the OP doesn't care, since this doesn't seem to have been their question; an important distinction all the same!

Comment: is there a way to check which time zones were stored in that fashion and which were not ?